# Install python package into directory relative to site-packages

Tags: python, distutils

I have a Python package that is one of a collection of company Python packages. When I run

```
python setup.py install
```

I want the package to be installed to a common company directory, along with other company packages. I want this directory to be relative to the default Python install directory, e.g.,

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/<company_name>/<python_package_name>
```

That is, I want to insert `<company_name>` into the installation path at install time.

I've seen ways to prefix this path, but can't seem to work out how to do what I've described.

Comment: Couldn't they all just be put into one big meta-package with the name `companyname`?

Comment: if you maintain that structure, e.g. your modules are called `company_name.python_package_name.yourmodule`, that is straightforward

Comment: The packages are standalone, and I would like to keep them logically separate. However, it would be nice for them to be grouped on the installation machine.

Comment: Does [`--install-lib`](https://docs.python.org/2/install/#custom-installation) work?

Comment: @user880772 install-lib installs relative to the pwd.

Comment: @user880772 sorry, the current working directory!

Comment: Looks like there is no good tutorial to create namespaced packages, so you would as well as copy here: https://bitbucket.org/miohtama/cryptoassets/src/176a54fadbf253e947f95dceab8eed20fa6ecfcf/setup.py?at=master and here https://bitbucket.org/miohtama/cryptoassets/src/176a54fadbf253e947f95dceab8eed20fa6ecfcf/cryptoassets/__init__.py?at=master

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately Python packaging doesn't work like that. You could probably bend it to work like that but that would be quite an effort for a person without experience in Python packaging and even for experienced persons the amount/output tradeoff would not make sense. You do not mention any motive to do this besides your personal preference.

Instead, to have well-managed and human-navigable package installation folder, I recommend you to study the following resources

- [PEP 0382 - Namespace Packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0382/): How to create packages like companyname.foobar, companyname.moomoo
- [Installing packages into a virtualenv - Python packaging installation guide (official)](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html#creating-virtual-environments)
- S[crambler: Symlink namespaced Python packages to a single folder](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scrambler/)